# Strange For Loop compiler error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop

I'm working on some code to fill arrays with user input, then I pass the array to a function (displayed below) that prints information about the array to the console.

The information I want to print should look like this:

```
array[5] {1, 1, 2, 1, 5}
newArray** = new short*[numRows] //10 rows, one for each single digit including zero
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
newArray[i] = newArray[numColumns];
}
...
cout << "There were " << newArray[leftCounter][1] << " instances of the number " << newArray[leftCounter][0] << ". " << endl;
```

Output: (example when leftCounter = 1)

"There were 3 instances of the number 1."

So I built the code, but my for loop for the cout statement is throwing up all kinds of errors. I've looked at it for a while now and I don't know what I've done wrong.

I'm not seeing any missed ;s. The {} are correct, I didn't accidentally put the loop out of scope or anything. I have no other uses of a variable called leftCounter.

Here's the code I wrote to accomplish the printing of my array.

```
vector<short> numberCounter(short input, vector<short> array);
void displayArray(vector<short> array);

... main() ... numberCounter ... main()... displayArray(array);

void displayArray(vector<short> array)
    {
        size_t arraySize = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(short));
        size_t numColumns = 2;
        size_t numRows = 10;    
        //First, I'm building a dynamic array that's equal the to size of my first array.
        short** newArray = new short*[numRows];

        //For each row, I want two columns.
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            //The second dimension of my array will have two values. The number, 0-9, and the number of time each of those numbers occurs in the array.
            newArray[i] = new short[numColumns];

            newArray[i][0] = i;     //newArray[i][0] should equal {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
            newArray[i][1] = 0;     //newArray[i][1] should all be initialized to 0 (so I can incriment them with the numbers of occurrances each of the digits.
        }

        //For each unique number in the array[], I'm incrimenting the "counter" by one. So if array[j] = 4, then newArray[4][0] would incriment by one, which adds to my count of 4s found in the first array.
        for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) //**edit 3: deleted the k = 0, I wasn't using that code anymore.**
        {
            newArray[array[j]][1]++;
        }

        cout << "Here are the counts of your number inputs." << endl;

        //Now, I will need to loop through my new array to display the counts the number of the numbers that occured at least once.
        for (int leftCounter = 0; leftCounter < arraySize; leftCounter++)
        {
            //If the counter was incrimented (thus, no longer has a value of zero)
            if (newArray[leftCounter][1] != 0)
            {
                cout << "There were " << newArray[leftCounter][1] << " instances of the number " << newArray[leftCounter][0] << ". " << endl;
            }
        }
         // free dynamically allocated memory
         for( int row = 0 ; row < numRows ; row++ )
         {
             delete[] newArray[row]; 
         }

         delete[] newArray;
        }
```

This code is producing these errors:

**Edit 3: I updated these errors to show the locations of the errors.**

```
Error   C2086   'int leftCounter': line 76 {cout for loop}  
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)   line    77  {the braces of the cout for-loop}
Error   C2447   '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) line  87 {the braces of the cout for-loop}    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Lab10_Exercise2 line    73  {cout statement before my cout for-loop}
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Lab10_Exercise2 line    76  {cout for-loop}
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    Lab10_Exercise2 line    86  {delete[] for loop}
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   line    68  {incrimentor for loop}
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   line    76  {cout for-loop}
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   line    86  {delete for-loop}
Error   C2059   syntax error: ';'   Line    70  {incrimentor for-loop}
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'   line    86  {delete for-loop}
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'delete'  line    91  {delete[] newArray[]}
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'for' line    76  {cout for-loop}
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'for' line    86  {delete[] for-loop}
Error   C2059   syntax error: '}'   line    93  {end of file}
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before ';'    line    76  {cout for-loop}
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before ';' line   86  {delete for-loop}
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '++'   line    76  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '++'   line    86  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<'    line    76  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<'    line    86  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<<'   line    73  {cout statement above the for loop}
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    line    77  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '{'    line    87  
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '}'    line    93  
Error   C2062   type 'short' unexpected line    68
```

**Edit: For clarity: The offending for-loop is this one:**

```
for (int leftCounter = 0; leftCounter < arraySize; leftCounter++)
    {
        //If the counter was incrimented (thus, no longer has a value of zero)
        if (newArray[leftCounter][1] != 0)
        {
            cout << "There were " << newArray[leftCounter][1] << " instances of the number " << newArray[leftCounter][0] << ". " << endl;
        }
    }
```

What happened? Am I missing something obvious?

**Edit 2: The delete[] for loop is also throwing the compiler errors. It seems that when I'm declaring ints in my loop, it's telling me I have a redefinition.**

***Edit 4: My entire code on this file.***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<short> numberCounter(short input, vector<short> array);
void displayArray(vector<short> array);

int main()
{
    vector<short> shortArray;
    short unsignedShort = 0;

    while (unsignedShort != 10)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a positive, single digit integer." << endl;
        cout << "Type 10 to submit your choices." << endl;
        cin >> unsignedShort;

        if (cin.fail() || ((unsignedShort < 0) || (unsignedShort > 10)))
        {
            //Clear the inputbuffer
            cin.clear();
            //Ignore the erroneous input
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Please type an integer." << endl;
        }
        else if (unsignedShort == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            shortArray = numberCounter(unsignedShort, shortArray);
        }
    }
    displayArray(shortArray);
}

vector<short> numberCounter(short input, vector<short> array)
{
    array.push_back(input);
    return array;
}

void displayArray(vector<short> array)
{
    size_t arraySize = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(short));
    size_t numColumns = 2;
    size_t numRows = 10;    
    //First, I'm building a dynamic array that's equal the to size of my first array.
    short** newArray = new short*[numRows];

    //For each row, I want two columns.
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        //The second dimension of my array will have two values. The number, 0-9, and the number of time each of those numbers occurs in the array.
        newArray[i] = new short[numColumns];

        newArray[i][0] = i;     //newArray[i][0] should equal {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
        newArray[i][1] = 0;     //newArray[i][1] should all be initialized to 0 (so I can incriment them with the numbers of occurrances each of the digits.
    }

    //For each unique number in the array[], I'm incrimenting the "counter" by one. So if array[j] = 4, then newArray[4][0] would incriment by one, which adds to my count of 4s found in the first array.
    for (short j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
    {
        newArray[array[j]][1]++;
    }

    cout << "Here are the counts of your number inputs." << endl;

    //Now, I will need to loop through my new array to count the number of non zero elements.
    for (int leftCounter = 0; leftCounter < arraySize; leftCounter++)
    {
        //If the counter was incrimented (thus, no longer has a value of zero)
        if (newArray[leftCounter][1] != 0)
        {
            cout << "There were " << newArray[leftCounter][1] << " instances of the number " << newArray[leftCounter][0] << ". " << endl;
        }
    }

    //Free dynamically allocated memory
    for (short row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
    {
        delete[] newArray[row];
    }

    delete[] newArray;

}
```

Comment: Is there a defined global variable named `leftCounter` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? And what compiler are you using?

Comment: It's one other problem in your code: `size_t arraySize = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(short));` will give wrong size (because `vector` contains not only values, but also some other information). Use `size_t arraySize = array.size();`

Comment: When you see these in C++ it's typically a trivial syntax error somewhere. It may not even be in the same file.

Comment: Where else does `leftCounter` occur in your code? It's not clear what causes your problem. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed No, I don't have any globals.

Comment: @melpomene Visual Studio, I can add the rest if you like.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Yikes, that could be annoying to find.

Comment: @JonathanMartin http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Pavel I don't use leftCounter anywhere else.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added it.

Comment: @Pavel > 
It's one other problem in your code: size_t arraySize = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(short)); will give wrong size (because vector contains not only values, but also some other information). Use size_t arraySize = array.size();<

Thanks! (I misread your commet. edited mine.)

Comment: Your code is missing an `#include <limits>`, but apart from that it compiles fine here.

Comment: @melpomene I made the change to my sizeof() statement and my code compiles now. But what do I need the #include <limits> for? I'm new to c++ but I thought that was used mostly for methods like min(), man(), is_integer() and such.

Comment: @JonathanMartin I needed it for `numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 1):

> It's one other problem in your code: size_t arraySize = (sizeof(array)
>   /
>
> sizeof(short)); will give wrong size (because vector contains not only
>   values, but also some other information). Use size_t arraySize =
>   array.size(); – Pavel 11 mins ago

Pavel found the problem. Thanks man!